# IE8 ignoring background "no-repeat" value

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a page that uses a background image to do rounded corners, and in IE8 on Windows XP the background image repeats.

(Link Dead)

It looks right in other browsers and even in "Compatability View" in IE8.

Does anyone know how to remove the repetion? I'm stumped!

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8 on Windows 7 in both compatibility mode and without. I can see no repetition. Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Paste in the appropriate CSS (and HTML) please.

Comment: Not saying it's the case here, but have you verified the html and css with an html validator ? Often, it's something small (- in stead of = or ; in stead of : , or the like.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE 8 and Window XP

Comment: Seems to work on some IE8 computers but not others

Comment: In IE8 the "Enter your personal details" falls out of the red box and forms don't show up. To me looks like a haslayout bug. Try applying a zoom:1 or clear after the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FORM elemement was terminated within a DIV element that started after it did. That is, the document was not "well formed" in XML parlance.

Answer (score 4):

We had this issue with an empty button tag, and changing the source from

```
<button type="submit" class="remove-group"/>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" class="remove-group"></button>
```

fixed it.

Not sure if that helps others who find this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out one of my tags wasn't well formed. i.e. I had `<a href="xxx"><div></a></div>`

Changed to `<a href="xxx"><div></div></a>` and got rid of the problem in ie8